# React-Native - Error: `StackViewTransitionConfigs` has been removed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting this error on a Android simulator **Error: `StackViewTransitionConfigs` has been removed.**

Ive looked at the react-navigation documentation and it does not seem like StackViewTransitionConfigs has been removed or moved.

I'm using "react-navigation": "4.0.7"

I know several packages have been moved but Ive found no posts related to this.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StackViewTransitionConfigs` was moved to [`react-navigation-stack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-stack) with all things related to stack navigators. You can check what changed in 4.0 [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases/tag/v4.0.0).